# How to add i18n feature to a large Pyramid project?

Tags: python, internationalization, pyramid

I have did these steps to try to add i18n feature to a current project.

## Add packages to myproject/product/setup.py

```
requires = [
...
+    'Babel',
+    'lingua',
]

setup(name='myproject.app.product',
...
+      message_extractors = { '.': [
+          ('**.py', 'lingua_python', None ),
+          ('**.pt', 'lingua_xml', None ),
+          ('src/myproject/app/product/**/templates/**.html', 'mako', None ),
+          ('src/myproject/app/product/**/templates/**.mako', 'mako', None ),
+          ('src/myproject/app/product/**/static/**', 'ignore', None ),
+          ]},
}
)
```

## Add config to myproject/product/setup.cfg

```
[compile_catalog]
directory = src/myproject/app/product/locale
domain = product
statistics = true

[extract_messages]
add_comments = TRANSLATORS:
output_file = src/myproject/app/product/locale/product.pot
width = 80

[init_catalog]
domain = product
input_file = src/myproject/app/product/locale/product.pot
output_dir = src/myproject/app/product/locale

[update_catalog]
domain = product
input_file = src/myproject/app/product/locale/product.pot
output_dir = src/myproject/app/product/locale
previous = true
```

## Add add_translation_dirs to myproject/product/src/myproject/app/product/**init**.py

```
config.add_translation_dirs('myproject.app.product:locale')
```

## Change html info and add a test output message to layout file: myproject/product/src/myproject/app/product/show/templates/pc/layout.html

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en"
      xmlns:tal="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/tal"
      xmlns:i18n="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/i18n"
      i18n:domain="product">

<h2 i18n:translate="search_documentation">Search documentation</h2>
```

## Add default_locale_name to application.ini

```
pyramid.default_locale_name = en
```

## Add test message to .po file: myproject/product/src/myproject/app/product/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/product.po

```
...
msgid "search_documentation"
msgstr "Search Documentation"
```

Finally, I compiled the translated .po files and started the project to view that layout page. it shows `Search documentation` but not `Search Documentation`. It means that the i18n setting is not work.

Where is the problem? How to config it?